# Why borrow DAI from compound has lower rate than borrow USDT?

Tags: defi, aave, tether, compound-protocol

As shown in the figure, borrowing Tether from compound have 10.73% APY, while borrow DAI from compound only have 4.64%.

However, we can exchange DAI or USDC to Tether in any exchange very easily, so such an APY premium for USDT should not exist. A big difference in APY should be arbitraged until there is not much difference. For instance, one could borrow USDC, exchange it for USDT and deposit that USDT at a higher rate than the USDC borrow. After some time, the APY difference would subside. But this is not happening.

Why is the interest rate gap between the two currencies so big?

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that as of today there is no more premium for USDT. What you were asking 7 days ago seems to no longer be happening and stablecoins APY have returned back to normal (more or less the same).

Comment: [Removed my answer because @Undead8 highlighted that I'd missed the point of the question :-) ]